# Phantomjs webdriver: can't switch from iframe to defaultContent

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, phpunit, phantomjs

I'm working in some functional tests, using PhantomJS on Webdriver mode, PHPUnit and the Facebook Webdriver implementation. Everything's fine but I'm having trouble with iframes.

If I change to an Iframe, then I can't switch back to the main document. The driver keeps pointing to the iframe.

I've prepared a super-simple example that fails:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="hi">Hi</p>
        <iframe id="test_iframe" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I execute this test:

```
$driver = \RemoteWebDriver::create(
    "http://localhost:4444",
    array(
        \WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'phantomjs'
    ),
    5000
);
$driver->get("http://localhost/test.php");
$driver->wait(5)->until(
    \WebDriverExpectedCondition::visibilityOfElementLocated(
        \WebDriverBy::cssSelector("p#hi")
    )
);

$driver->switchTo()->frame(
    $driver->findElement(
        \WebDriverBy::id("test_iframe")
    )
);

$driver->wait(7)->until(
    \WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(
        \WebDriverBy::cssSelector("h1")
    )
);

$driver->switchTo()->defaultContent();
var_dump($driver->getPageSource());
```

And I get the iframe HTML dumped. I've tried waiting for elements, sleeping some seconds but nothing works.

Anyone has a clue on solving this? regards